# Cómo hacer una ventana modal despues de respuesta de correo

Tags: php, html, modal, ventana

Estoy empezando en el mundo de la programación y rengo una duda y es que no se como hacer que después de que se envie el formulario de correo aparezca una ventana la cual diga que el coreo ha sido enviado correctamente o que no ha sido enviado. Este el el código php que tengo para verificar el formulario pero no se como hacer opara que cargue lnuevamente la página y a la vez muestra dicha ventana. Mil gracias

```
<?php
// capturo los datos
$nombre = $_REQUEST['form-name'];
//$telefono =  $_REQUEST['telefono'];
$correo =  $_REQUEST['form-email'];
$asunto = $_REQUEST['form-subject'];
$comentarios =  $_REQUEST['form-message'];

//if ( $_REQUEST['form-name'] & $_REQUEST['telefono'] & $_REQUEST['form-email'] & $_REQUEST['form-message'])  {
if ( $_REQUEST['form-name'] & $_REQUEST['form-email'] & $_REQUEST['form-message'])  {
    // comprobamos si el correo es valido
    $mail_correcto = 0;
    //compruebo unas cosas primeras
    if ((strlen($correo) >= 6) && (substr_count($correo,"@") == 1) && (substr($correo,0,1) != "@") && (substr($correo,strlen($correo)-1,1) != "@")){
        if ((!strstr($correo,"'")) && (!strstr($correo,"\"")) && (!strstr($correo,"\\")) && (!strstr($correo,"\$")) && (!strstr($correo," "))) {
            //miro si tiene caracter .
            if (substr_count($correo,".")>= 1){
                //obtengo la terminacion del dominio
                $term_dom = substr(strrchr ($correo, '.'),1);
                //compruebo que la terminación del dominio sea correcta
                if (strlen($term_dom)>1 && strlen($term_dom)<5 && (!strstr($term_dom,"@")) ){
                    //compruebo que lo de antes del dominio sea correcto
                    $antes_dom = substr($correo,0,strlen($correo) - strlen($term_dom) - 1);
                    $caracter_ult = substr($antes_dom,strlen($antes_dom)-1,1);
                    if ($caracter_ult != "@" && $caracter_ult != "."){
                        $mail_correcto = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if ($mail_correcto) {
       // envio los datos
        $mymail =  "contacto@tiagodelgado.es";
        $subject = "Contacto desde la pagina web";
        $mensaje = "<font face=Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif>";
            $mensaje = $mensaje . "<strong>" . ($nombre) . "</strong> relleno los datos siguientes:<br /><br />";
            $mensaje = $mensaje . "<strong>Nombre y apellido:</strong> " . ($nombre) . "<br />";
            //$mensaje = $mensaje . "<strong>Tel&eacute;fono:</strong> " . ($telefono) . "<br />";
            $mensaje = $mensaje . "<strong>Correo:</strong> " . ($correo) . "<br />";
            $mensaje = $mensaje . "<strong>Asunto:</strong> " . ($asunto) . "<br />";
            $mensaje = $mensaje . "<strong>Mensaje:</strong> " . ($comentarios) . "<br />";
        $mensaje = $mensaje . "</font>";
        $header = "From:". $correo ."\nReply-To:". $correo ."\n";
        $header .= "X-Mailer:PHP/".phpversion()."\n";
        $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
        
        mail($mymail, $subject, utf8_decode($mensaje) ,$header);
        //header('Location: contacto.php?envio=ok');
        header('Location: index_en.html');
    }else{
       header   ('Location: index_en.html?envio=form-email&form-name='. $nombre.'&form-email='.$correo.'&form-subject='.$asunto.'&form-message='.$comentarios.'');
    }
} else {
    //header    ('Location: contacto.php?envio=error&nombre='. $nombre.'&telefono='.$telefono.'&correo='.$correo.'&asunto='.$asunto.'&comentarios='.$comentarios.'');
    header  ('Location: index_en.html');
}
```

?>

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema actualmente? ¿Qué hace tu actual código? De todos modos, para mostrar una ventana modal tendrás que usar Javascript y para interactuar en este tipo de casos es mejor usar Ajax, el cual te permite comunicar entre el cliente (HTML, Formulario) con el servidor (PHP, código que usas para enviar el email) sin necesidad de recargar la página.

Comment: Si quieres lo puedes hacer con `header ... location`, mandando a un archivo que *parezca* un modal ... pero esto es prehistórico hoy en día, porque existen herramientas como Ajax o la API Fetch de Javascript para comunicar entre cliente y servidor sin necesidad de recargar la página. Así, con un simple `alert()` mostrarías que el correo fue enviado o no.

Answer (score 0):

Puede generarlo con SweetAlert. Verificando si el correo se ha enviado que muestre un tipo de alert (success) y si no se ha enviado un alert de error.

Puede considerar el siguiente ejemplo básico que hice para que haga su validación al momento de enviar el correo.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/11.4.24/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
            <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
            <input name="mail" type="text" placeholder="Email">
            <input name="sub" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        <?php
    if(isset($_POST['sub'])){
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $email=$_POST['mail'];
        if(empty($name) || empty($email)){
        ?>
        <script>
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: 'Invalid',
                text: 'Debe Escribir algo'
                /* Acá puede redireccionar */
            })
        </script>
        <?php
        }
        else{
        ?>
            <script>
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'success',
                title: 'Listo !!!',
                text: 'Nombre ' + "<?php echo $name ?> y correo " + "<?php echo $email ?>"
                /* Acá puede redireccionar */
            })
        </script>
        <?php
        }
}
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Espero le sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, creo que es lo que estaba buscando. Gracias